# Find the substring between two "/"

Tags: java, string

For this program the user is told to input a data in the form of "mm/dd/yyyy" and I'm trying to use the `indexOf()` method with the parameter of "/" to break the date string into three substrings.

I tried doing this:

```java
String monthString = dateString.substring(0,dateString.indexOf("/"));
    String dayString = 
    dateString.substring(dateString.indexOf("/"),DateString.indexOf("/")+1)
```

Thank you.
Edit. Thank you all for your responses, but my teacher said that i cannot use the split fucntion. He said I can solve this using just indexOf("/") and substring(). I'll need two calls to indexOf("/") and four calls to substring().

Comment: use `split` to split the date string to parts.

Comment: Depending what you are doing with the parts later on you may also consider a date parsing method (e.g. `LocalDate.parse`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] element = dateString.split("/");
String strDay = element[0];
String strMonth = element[1];
String strYear = element[2];
```

This is what you're looking for.

Comment: You could even convert each array element into a integer value: `int month = Integer.parseInt(element[0]);` since your date format is in `MM/dd/yyyy` and not `dd/MM/yyyy`.

Comment: My answer is suited with the question, but for a better solution, you can try to parse the dateString to `Date`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of split() method you can use **Java Date API**

```
  String dateString = "10/30/2018";
    try {
        DateFormat dateFromatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(dateFromatter.parse(dateString));
        System.out.println("Date:" + calendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
        System.out.println("Month:" + calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        System.out.println("Year:" + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Output

```
Date:30
Month:9
Year:2018
```

For month field **Calendar.MONTH** starts from 0 which mean Jan=0,Feb=1 Refer [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH)

Answer (score 0):

`dateString.split("[/]");` gives you the array of string. `split()` function take input in `regex` thats why `"[]"` are added.

if the dateString is "dd/mm/yy" then `dateString.split("[/]")` return the `String` array consists of `{"dd","mm","yy"}`.

Comment: what do the square brackets do?

Comment: Regex write in square brackets.

Comment: `dateString.split("/");` - works fine, why use `"[/]"`?

Comment: in that case "/" not a regular expression. but if you entered regular expression without square brackets it may cause a problem. so its good practice t use a square brackets. it work fine for both cases.

Comment: @KhalidShah square brackets in a regular expression denote a character class. I.e. this construct matches any one of the characters between it. "/" is a perfectly fine regular expression matching a single slash.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 or above and **actually you are handling date and time**, then I think you should have a try at [`LocalDate.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) and as to your problem then you can achieve it easily as:

```
LocalDate theDate = LocalDate.parse("08/22/2018", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/d/yyyy"));
System.out.println("year: " + theDate.getYear() + " month: " + theDate.getMonthValue() + " day: " + theDate.getDayOfMonth());
```

the output will be:

```
year: 2018 month: 8 day: 22
```